# Retaining study participants in a longitudinal research study

Tags: psychology, experiment-design

Which methods can be followed to retain participants in a longitudinal research study?

We tried to retain participants by sending reminder messages, and also a bonus at the second time point, but none of these two methods have worked so far. Only half of the participants came back to take part at the second time point. It hampers the counterbalancing of different variables. Would you please share your experiences to retain participants?

Comment: This would be more relevant for https://psychology.stackexchange.com/ -- you are more likely to get useful answers over there. That being said, retention of participants in longitudinal study is difficult. What do you mean by bonus at the second time -- do you mean monetary reward or something else?